# Suppress password change email when accepting invitation with Devise Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have enabled password change notifications using

`config.send_password_change_notification = true`

However, currently when a user accepts an invitation triggered by Devise Invitable they are receiving a password change email.
e.g.

```
Started PUT "/users/invitation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-20 16:14:41 +0100
Processing by UsersController::InvitationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9gDHF+Vm6oxGPILonaQe7NSnhytoQGsOBm0eVEMziSS6J93UFnoHSwouyV9NezleulmstfcNW8Axr/nJajBBYw==", "user"=>{"invitation_token"=>"98usw1XW4w31UuCd_DzQ", "full_name"=>"example", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Set my password"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["invitation_token", "0a0787a3270a097c22a1272f49040c5c11d67b2cb222059d88d85f35e95c8d78"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "invitation_token" = $1, "encrypted_password" = $2, "full_name" = $3, "invitation_accepted_at" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "users"."id" = $6  [["invitation_token", nil], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$qQKCx4FWQS2ARyiiGf8zdeAn7XLBa0clbWuv1cH1c1cXWbF65VMd6"], ["full_name", "example"], ["invitation_accepted_at", "2017-10-20 16:14:41.323768"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-20 16:14:41.324814"], ["id", 9]]
DeviseMailer#password_change: processed outbound mail in 1.7ms
Sent mail to example@example.com (195.9ms)
```

Is it possible to suppress the notification if the user is accepting an invitation but continue to send it for other password change events?

*Environment info:*

```
Rails 5.1.4
devise (4.3.0, 4.2.1)
devise_invitable (1.7.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured this out.
Add the following to `app/models/user.rb`

```
 def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    unless(notification == :password_change && sign_in_count.zero?)
      super
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you for pointing me in the right direction, here is my take on this

```rb
def send_password_change_notification
    super unless accepting_invitation?
end
```

`accepting_invitation?` is a variable set on the beginning of the process

As a bonus, it bugged me that when you ask for a password recover it would prompt you with a success message and don't do anything, with this it would prompt with an error message.

**[:en, :errors, :messages, :invitation_active]** on your locales or just use default **:not_found**

```
def send_reset_password_instructions
    if invited_to_sign_up?
        self.errors.add :email, :invitation_active
    else
        super
    end
end
```